# Java adding to a unknown type generic list

Tags: java, generics, reflection, classloader

I've come into something I haven't come across before in Java and that is, I need to create a new instance of say the ArrayList class at runtime without assigning a known type then add data to the list. It sounds a bit vague so here is an example:

```
Class<?> c = i.getClass();

Constructor<?> con = ArrayList.class.getConstructor();
ArrayList<?> al = (ArrayList<?>)con.newInstance();

al.add("something");
```

Now the reason I'm doing this versus just using generics is because generics are already being used heavily and the "i" variable in this example would be given to use as type "?". I would really rather not throw in another generic as this would cause more work for the user and would be much less flexible in the end design. Is there any way to use something like below (Note: what is below doesn't work). Anyone have ideas?

```
ArrayList<c> al = (ArrayList<c>)con.newInstance();
```

Comment: Generics is for compile time validation. At runtime, you might as well not worry about generic types and just use a non-generic `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Bala R You're right, I can just remove the generics, I was just wondering if there was a way to pull it from the class to ensure validation. Thanks, you're idea will probably work for my purposes.

Comment: I have to ask, what purpose is a list for which you don't know the type of the data that it will contain?

Comment: It's part of an API that I am working on. The reason I don't know what data is because it's coming from an external source that can change depending the users configuration. Basically, much is determined at run-time vs. compile time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't add objects in a Collection defined using wildcards generics. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504208/another-java-generic-question/6504576#6504576) might help you.

Indeed you are creating a collection that is, yes, the super type of every collection, and as such, can be assigned to any collection of generics; but it's too generic to allow any kind of add operation as there is no way the compiler can check the type of what you're adding. And that's exactly what generics are meant to : type checking.

I suggest you read the thread and see that it also apply to what you wanna do.

Your collection is just too generic to allow anything to be added in. The problem has nothing to do with the right hand side of the asignment (using a singleton or reflection), it's in the left hand side declaration type using wildcards.

Answer (score 8):

If I get what you mean, you have a class C, which is unknown at compile time, and you want to create an `ArrayList<C>`, in a type safe way. This is possible:

```
Class<?> c = ...;
ArrayList<?> al = listOf(c);

static <T> ArrayList<T> listOf(Class<T> clazz)
{
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

This is the *theoretically* correct way of doing it. But who cares. We all know about type erasure, and there's no chance Java will drop type erasure and add runtime type for type parameters. So you can just use raw types and cast freely, as long as you know what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, you can create a unknown generic ArrayList but then you can't add something to it, which is where my question comes into play.

Comment: how is this different from `ArrayList<?> al = new ArrayList<SomeRandomType>();`?

Comment: @newacct presumably, there's an out-of-band agreement, at some point, the list can be safely(by app logic) cast to `ArrayList<X>` and an `X` object is added to it. with erasure, neither the cast nor the add is a problem. with reification it's another story.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use `ArrayList<Object>`, to which you can `add()` anything.

Comment: True, but then then they are of Object type, no longer an unknown type. This would work as far as adding but returns an casted Object ArrayList. The user then would have to cast each one back. Now, Java since 1.4, I believe, does retain the extra data from their subclasses but not quiet what I need.

Comment: @ars265: but since you don't know the type at compile time, you will have to cast it back anyway

Comment: @newacct: That is true, but I'm developing a framework so the user of the framework would have received the result. I was looking for something a little different. I ended up building a linq type class for the environment.