# Java how to pass a loaded class parameter type as a generic argument?

Tags: java, class, generics, arguments, loaded

I would like to load a java class dynamically, and then add objects created with this class in an `ObservableList<myLoadedClass>` for example.

```
Class<?> thisClass = Class.forName("Point", true, classLoader);
Object iClass = thisClass.newInstance();
...
ObservableList<thisClass> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

The last line cause error

> Cannot find symbol: class thisClass...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `thisClass` is a variable, not a type variable.

Comment: You can still use ObservableList<?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok for the wildcard but then ...

```
Class<?> thisClass = Class.forName("Point", true, classLoader);
Object iClass = thisClass.newInstance();
...
ObservableList<?> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
data.addAll(iClass);
```

Last line cause: No suitable method found for addAll(Object).

Any ideas?

---

Five (or a bit more ;-) minutes later...

Instead of wildcard, 'Object' made the trick. Inspired by [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6504208/another-java-generic-question/6504576#6504576) where they explain: "So a Collection of unknown type is not a collection that can take any type. It only takes the unknown type. And as we don't know that type (its unknown ;) ), we can never add a value, because no type in java is a subclass of the unknown type."

So, for now, my solution is:

```
Class<?> thisClass = Class.forName("Point", true, classLoader);
Object iClass = thisClass.newInstance();
...
ObservableList<Object> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
data.addAll(iClass);

// Sample Point class method
Method getXMethod = thisClass.getDeclaredMethod("getX");

System.out.println(getXMethod.invoke(data.get(0)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't know what type is `thisClass` at compile time - that is what wildcards are for:

```
ObservableList<?> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

Comment: what about `ObservableList<Class<?>>` ?

Comment: @Hiru that's fine if you want to store `Class<?>`, as opposed to instances of the classes. However, the question says "add objects created with this class in an ObservableList"

Comment: @Hiru I think the op wants a `List<Point>` not a `List<Class<Point>>`